# parse JSON using shell script

Tags: json, linux, macos, shell

I need to parse JSON using shell script (I used to use Python, but not allowed in this specific environment), in this example, I want to get the value of `b1`, which is `6.5`, anyone have any experience?

Using Linux/Mac OSX.

```
{
    "value": {
        "a1": {
            "amount": "5.5",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "b1": {
            "amount": "6.5",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "c1": {
            "d1": {
                "amount": "7.5",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "e1": {
                "amount": "8.5",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "f1": {
                "amount": "9.5",
                "currency": "USD"
            }
        },
        "g1": {
            "amount": "10.5",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh

Comment: or https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk if you have AWK

Comment: but AFAIR oython is a standart component of any OS X installation, isn't it?

Comment: @user3159253, thanks and do you think write a regular expression is easier for me? I just need to read a specific field b1.

Comment: @user3159253, do you mean Python? `oython` is?

Comment: @user3159253, I see it requires install, actually, I cannot install using `npm install -g JSON.sh`, since permission is restricted. I can execute shall script, but not able to install anything additional. Any further ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to install anything with NPM. Just look at [test/parse-test.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh/blob/master/test/parse-test.sh). All you need is to create a shell script which includes JSON.sh via `source` (== `.`) command and then extracts necessary data. Just two files created in your home dir. To use an instantly ready library with a decent parser or to stay with a regular expression — well, it's your choice, indeed. If you or your customer plan to perform any further development — I'd stay with the library.

Comment: @user3159253, cool, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people search.

Comment: Well, I haven't added any new information. Google already gives JSON.sh as one of the first choices for "JSON shell parser" query. So I doubt we need to multiply entities without ncecessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsawk:

curl -Ls http://github.com/micha/jsawk/raw/master/jsawk > jsawk

bash jsawk < /tmp/my_data.json 'return this.value.b1.amount'

Comment: Thanks George, vote up and mark your reply as answer.